# Converting part of project into a dll

Tags: c#, mvvm, dll

I have made a C# project as a MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel), and i need to convert the model part of my project into a dll.

I already know that i can go and change the output type of the project to Class Library, but this gives me some problems in my ViewModel as it tries to convert the entire project into a dll.

The model part is only .cs files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a new class library project to your solution, move the .cs files you want to separate to the new project, and then add a reference to the new project in your original project.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try that.
What sort of reference is it that i have to make?

Comment: To do that, you need to find "References" folder in your original project, right click -> add reference. Having a reference to an another project means that the original project needs the other one (dll) to work.

Comment: I think it almost works, but i am getting some problems in my app.xaml file now after excluding the model from the main project.

A line such as: <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:UMLClass}"> gives the error ' The name "UMLClass" does not exist in the namespace "cld-namespace:UMLGen.Model"'. It seems that the xaml file is not aware that it should get that information from the xaml file now?

Comment: Nvm, i fixed it by adding ;assembly=ModelDLL at the end of my reference. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since you are following **MVVM** you can add WPF Usercontrol library project. 
This is an another way of creating library file which includes UI.

[image]

Comment: How do i make a reference to the dll that i've created from this project?

Comment: Right click -> add reference-> browse the location, probably **bin/debug/file.dll** and select your dll

Comment: I've successfully added it as a reference now, but my app.xaml file doesn't seem to register the change. I have code such as '<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:UMLClass}">', where Model is 'xmlns:Model="cld-namespace:UMLGen.Model"', but it gives me the error 'The name "UMLClass" does not exist in the namespace "cld-namespace:UMLGen.Model"' when building the solution.

Comment: Nvm, i fixed it by adding ;assembly=ModelDLL at the end of the reference to the namespace.